# How I can set limit line in List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to set a limit in my list; I want it to show only 5 lines.

Here’s my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let allnum = ["1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.allnum , id: \.self) { num in
                Text("\(num)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I change `List` to `List(0 ..< 5) { _ in`, I see 5 lines, but with all elements in the array.

any advice pls

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn’t you do the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let allnum = ["1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.allnum[0 ..< 5], id: \.self) { num in
                Text("\(num)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you take only a range of the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

## 3 Steps notes for about code

1. You should take only first `n` elements (here is `5`) of the array as the dataSource.
2. `List` does not require `ForEach`.
3. Simple closures arguments does not need a name.

So the minimal refactored working code for the `body` would be:

```
var body: some View {
    List(allnum.prefix(5), id: \.self) { Text($0) }
}
```

---

## More less code

If you implement this extension somewhere:

```
extension String: Identifiable { public var id: String { self } }
```

The list code would be even more smaller and simpler like:

```
List(allnum.prefix(5)) { Text($0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a ForEach with a count from 0 to <5 and used the number to index the array.  In production code you probably want a test to make sure that you don't attempt to use an index beyond the end of the array.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let allnum = ["1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5 ) { num in
                Text("\(self.allnum[num])")
            }
        }
    }
}
```